# Regex: Delete all operators/punctuation marks after the last word on a line

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have this sentence:

```
knowledge and spread of metaphysics - can become famous for cures and treatments : -= , *
```

I want to delete all operators/punctuation marks after the last word on a line, so the output should be:

```
knowledge and spread of metaphysics - can become famous for cures and treatments.
```

can anyone help me with a solution?

Comment: Your question is to broad please be more specific. Do you want to replace everything after given string to `.`? Some kind of special characters to dot? Something else?... What you've tried to solve it? Why that doesn't work?

Comment: I want to delate all special characters (except dot) after the last word on the line, and and to replace with dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comment:

> I want to delete all special characters (except dot) after the last word on the line, and to replace with dot.

This does the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `[^a-z]*$`
- Replace with: `.`
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
[^a-z]*     # 0 or more non alpha
$           # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: @JustMe: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)